# ALT (opt) key on MacBook Pro not working as hotkey modifier

Tags: osx, keymap

I'm on a MBP running macOS Catalina, and using a fresh install of Blender 3.0. My <kbd>opt</kbd> key isn't working when I attempt to use it as a hotkey modifier. For instance, when I have try to move a vertex and hit <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to change it to the shrink/fatten tool.

I have reset the keybinding for specific commands and it recognizes the <kbd>opt</kbd> key when I input the new key combination, but not when I'm trying to use it in viewport.

I'm using a bluetooth keyboard, and it's doing the same thing on both the external as well as onboard keyboard.

update: <kbd>opt</kbd> is working to modify the selection, so I know blender is recognizing the <kbd>opt</kbd> key, it just doesn't work to modify hot keys.

Comment: there is not alt key on a mbp. there is a control, option and command key. which one do you mean!?

Comment: Thanks for catching that! The <kbd>opt</kbd> key seems to replace the alt key in blender on a mac, and it's the one that I've been using and meant in my question. I've updated my question with the correct information.

Comment: i remember i had some difficulties on my mbp too in 3.0. Did you try out 3.1... if possible?